Two students develop dangerous symbiotic relationship
I watched a movie some years ago (maybe 8), and I can't recall its name (I was sure it was "Dangerous minds", at least translated into Spanish, but that seems to be a completely different movie). 
There was this group of students attending a prestigious school, one of which was really smart. Then, a new guy joins the school and a strange (I remember the word "symbiotic") relationship starts to develop between the smart guy and the new, smarter guy.
At some point it is implied that the new guy can read the thoughts of the smart one. The new guy starts to commit murders, up to the point when he kills the girlfriend of the smart guy, and is later killed by him.
If my memory doesn't fail me, towards the end it is implied that the smart guy desecrated the tomb of his girlfriend and had sex with her.
It did not include magic; it was some kind of psycho thriller.

Is Megan Fox part of the film? Could it be Jeniffers Body?

@MarioGarcia no, it was Like Minds. Thanks anyway.

Could it be Like Minds (2006)

A forensic psychologist, Sally Rowe, is appointed by police to
  determine whether there's enough evidence to lay murder charges
  against 17 year old Alex, accused in the shotgun death of his school
  mate Nigel. With no tangible evidence, the detective on the case is
  under pressure from Alex's influential father to have the charges
  dropped. Delving deeply into Alex and Nigel's bizarre symbiotic pact,
  Rowe discovers that though dead, Nigel's psychological effect on Alex
  is far from diminished.

From Wikipedia:

Alex Forbes attends a boarding school where his father is principal. A
  new student, Nigel Colbie, is placed in Alex's room. Nigel has a
  father who is in the same secret society as Alex's father. Nigel,
  however, is unusual, and in Alex's words "had this morbid fascination
  with all things dead." Nigel keeps animals preserved in jars, and
  dissects them. Alex complains to his father, and Nigel is moved. But
  Alex can't seem to stop thinking about him. He does, however, start to
  flirt with a girl named Susan, whom Nigel kills. Later on, Nigel
  explained that there are a series of things that must happen for them
  to gain "eternity."


That's exactly the one! Thanks a lot. The Spanish title of the movie is indeed  "Dangerous minds", but only for the Argentine release. I was never going to find it! On a sidenote, I'm shocked by the bad reviews the movie got.. I remember it to be really good.
